# PHPUnit is complaining about incompatible static method declarations

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I am using Zend FW 1 and PHPUnit 3.5.15.

In a parent class I am declaring `public static function _doInsert(DomainObject $object)` and I am overriding this in a child class.

The only difference in the method signature of the child class is that it hints for an object that is more specific than `DomainObject`, something like `DomainObjectChild`.  This seems to work fine as far as my application goes, however PHPUnit chokes with an error.  It says that the declaration of the method in the child class should be compatible with that of the parent.

Any ideas, my bright friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an `E_STRICT` level warning that is coming from PHP, not PHPUnit. Check your `error_reporting` settings for the CLI version of PHP (which usually has a seperate php.ini file) or any PHP settings being overridden in your PHPUnit configuration.

You can either fix the problem in your code to remove the warning, or change the error_reporting level that PHPUnit is using.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that was spot on.  Any ideas why this would raise an E_STRICT error?

Comment: My guess is that with the addition of [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) where static methods truly can be overridden, PHP checks that the signatures match "just in case" you use it.